# How to choose View dynamically based on current DataContext view model

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `Page` which will receive a different `DataContext` (View Model), dynamically.

I can't figure out how to use `DataTemplate` in a `switch/case` fashion, to render the appropriate view based on the current context.

I would imagine that I will have multiple DataTemplates like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type LocalViewModels:ABC}">
  <LocalViews:ABC/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

but can't figure out in what container to put them. Only one of them will be rendered at a time, so `ListBox` makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following XAML of a Window

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ABC}">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

you can simply assign an instance of `ABC` to the Window's `DataContext` to create the templated view.

```
class ABC
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

...
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new ABC { Text = "Hello, World." };
}
```

---

All details are here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx).